# Is there a different implementation to avoid my long switch statement?

Tags: ios, uibutton, switch-statement

In my iOS app, I have a view containing around 33 buttons  (I'm creating an interactive map).  Each button corresponds to a building.  And each button I want to modally present a different view controller based on the selected button.

So my first thought was to tag all the buttons, and create a 33 case long switch statement.  Looking at my code, there has to be a better way to do it, but my brain isn't coming up with the solution. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the button tag as the index into an array giving you the configuration for the view to show.

If you are using different view controller classes for the presentation of some buildings then you can have an identifier (or, if you want, the class name) in the configuration.

Comment: So I would create an array of 33 view controllers every time a button is clicked? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Don't create the controllers up front in the array. Just add the information you need to use to create them to the array (maybe a display name, class name, building identity, some configuration). Then pass that info to a new view controller instance created when the button is tapped.

Comment: And the array is created at the same time as the buttons are configured (given tags). All you do when a button is pressed is read info out of the array.